# Best way to indicate no rating in a rating matrix?

Tags: python, rating-system, recommendation-engine

I am building a recommender system using a USER-ITEM rating matrix. The user rates the items 1-5. However, I have used 0 to indicate if the user has not rated this item and think it might be affecting the predicted ratings the recommender is outputting.

What is the best way to indicate that the user has not rated a particular item in a rating matrix?

Answer (score 0):

just an idea

```
class matrix():
    def __init__(self):
        self.rated = False
        self.rating = 0

    def rate(self):
        if not self.rated:
            rating logic goes here
            self.rated = True
        else:
            print("already rated")
```